# Join com Active Record do Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, query, active-record

Fiz uma `query` que esta rodando ok e estou passando para o Active Record do Codeigniter mas não esta dando certo por causa de um join que esta um pouco fora com convencional, será que alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

```
$query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT count(rl.id) as total, rl.dt_validate
    FROM respostas r
    JOIN respostas_log rl 
        ON rl.id = (select max(rl2.id) from respostas_log rl2 where rl2.respostas_id = r.id)
    GROUP BY rl.dt_validate
    ");
```

E com o Active Record não roda....

```
$query = $this->db
        ->select('count(rl.id) as total, rl.dt_validate')
        ->from('respostas r')
        ->join('respostas_log rl', "rl.id = (select max(rl2.id) from respostas_log rl2 where rl2.respostas_id = mr.id)")
        ->group_by('rl.dt_validate')
        ->get();
```

Será que alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

**Explicação:**

*O método é esse:*

```php
public function join($table, $cond, $type = '')
{
    if ($type != '')
    {
        $type = strtoupper(trim($type));

        if ( ! in_array($type, array('LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'OUTER', 'INNER', 'LEFT OUTER', 'RIGHT OUTER')))
        {
            $type = '';
        }
        else
        {
            $type .= ' ';
        }
    }
    // Extract any aliases that might exist.  We use this information
    // in the _protect_identifiers to know whether to add a table prefix
    $this->_track_aliases($table);
    // Strip apart the condition and protect the identifiers
    if (preg_match('/([\w\.]+)([\W\s]+)(.+)/', $cond, $match))
    {
        $match[1] = $this->_protect_identifiers($match[1]);
        $match[3] = $this->_protect_identifiers($match[3]);

        $cond = $match[1].$match[2].$match[3];
    }
    // Assemble the JOIN statement
    $join = $type.'JOIN '.$this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE).' ON '.$cond;
    $this->ar_join[] = $join;
    if ($this->ar_caching === TRUE)
    {
        $this->ar_cache_join[] = $join;
        $this->ar_cache_exists[] = 'join';
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Então, `$table` é o nome da tabela que relaciona a `$cond` é a condição e o `$type` que pode ser alguns desses `'LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'OUTER', 'INNER', 'LEFT OUTER', 'RIGHT OUTER'`

Exemplo

```php
$this->db->from('cliente')
    ->join('telefone', 'cliente.id = telefone.clienteid', 'left')
    ->get()
    ->result();
```

Esse é o formato ele é limitado em colocar um SQL ali porque por automático ele coloca um escape (**`**), sendo essa SQL gerada por ele:

```php
SELECT * FROM (`cliente`) LEFT JOIN `telefone` ON `cliente`.`id` = `telefone`.`clienteid`
```

***Solução:***

```php
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(rl.id) as total, rl.dt_validate FROM respostas r JOIN respostas_log rl ON rl.id = (select max(rl2.id) from respostas_log rl2 where rl2.respostas_id = r.id) GROUP BY rl.dt_validate");
```

Na verdade você já tem a solução e quando se faz um SQL complexa é a melhor forma de executar instruções SQL no CodeIgniter.

Comment: Então, vi que colocou a explicação, legal, eu já tinha até visto isso no Core do CI, e a solução é a mesma que a minha correto. O que eu estava tentando era passar para o AR para ficar mais limpo algumas condicionais antes da query em si.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz pelo que eu sei é limitado nesse sentido, já tenho site com CodeIgniter, e por isso é melhor usar `$this->db->query`